# Stripe payment implementation with SCA credit card authentication

Tags: forms, xamarin, stripe-payments, credit-card

I am trying to build Xamarin Forms native Stripe payment process.
Here is sample that is working when card in not requiring SCA (secure client authentication), but I would like also to support SCA, 
I am unable to understand exactly how to do it as I am supposed to get notification and open a separate web view where additional authorization will be performed.
I cannot decipher where info on what URL needs to be opened, and if payment is success, how to provide info in mobile app that it was succesfull.

Here is link to sample containing Xamarin Sample App, as well as backend service
https://gitlab.com/dn-misc/xamformsstripe

Also if someone managed to create xamarin bindings for
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android
There is basic integration option so maybe creating dependency service interacting with native SDK could be a path

Any help will be appreciated :wink:

Thanx,
D

Answer (score 1):

Short of creating your own [iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-swift/) or [Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/) bindings, as you noted, you have two main choices:

1. Use a [WebView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview) to load [Stripe.js and Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js) and call `confirmCardPayment` from there.
2. If you've already got a Payment Method to use with a Payment Intent, you can [manually redirect to the authentication url](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/3d-secure#manual-redirect) when you encounter the `requires_action` status.

Comment: As I am pursuing  second path where Payment method and Payment intent is created, for cards requiring SCA I am getting require_action status. What I am confused about is where can I pool URL for manual redirection?
I would open a webview in forms app with this url, also when payment is sucessfull how can I notify client?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about where to pool the URL. Pool how? When successful, you can redirect back to your app if waiting synchronously or you can manage a connection to your server/back-end which is set to receive webhooks.

Comment: HI, after I get (server side) paymentIntent.Status == "requires_action" I am checking paymentIntent.NextAction.Type and I can see it is set to redirect_to_url, and I am able to get url from paymentIntent.NextAction.RedirectToUrl.Url. I can open webView on client. client authorizes transaction and is redirected to paymentIntent.NextAction.RedirectToUrl.ReturnUrl.  What is missing for me now is how do I get notification from stripe about success / failure of transaction, as I need to notify client on end result.